# Android In-app billing for one-time billing

Tags: android, in-app-billing

Suppose: users need to log-in account to run the application and buy apps items.
Story:There is one user called John. He registers two accounts in the application named "John1" and "John2".
Second, John uses his only one gmail account for purchase items - "john@gmail.com"
The question is, John log-in as John1 and buy item1. Then, he log-out and log-in as John2.
As the item1 is set as one-time billing, does John2 need to pay once more for buying item1?
For me, as he is using separate account, he should pay once more.
But I don't how Google handle it.
So, for both bases, how should I pro grammatically handle them?
Thanks.

Comment: This is not a programming question

Comment: because I need to handle depends on how Google handles

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that by "one-time billing" you mean a "managed" item.
If so, the user won't be able to purchase the item again, since his account on Google Play already purchased this item.

If you want to make the user buy it again, make the item "unmanaged" and store the data on your server-side DB to know which app-users (and not Google Play users) bought what.

Comment: managed means In-app products and unmanaged means Subscriptions in this site:http://developer.android.com/guide/google/play/billing/billing_overview.html ??

Comment: No. Subscriptions are subscriptions (renewed every time period). Managed means that Google "manages" the purchase per Google Play account and won't allow more than 1 purchase for a managed item for the same Google Play account. Unmanaged means that the same Google Play account can purchase more this item more than once

Answer (score 1):

You should not allow user to register with same email.He has to use diffrent email for diffrent account thats the right and common way.